# Azure Kubernetes Service - Persistent Volume / Persistent Volume Claim change permissions

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-storage, azure-aks, persistent-volumes

I'm new with Azure infrastructure and I'm trying to deploy Jenkins on AKS and be able to preserve all of my Jenkins data if the container stopped working and I run with a permissions issue for my newly created PVC.

I want to change the permissions for a specific folder and files in the PVC and the "chmod" command looks like running but doesn't do anything and the permissions are still set to 777 instead of my wanted permissions.

I have noticed that the Storage Class default permissions value for dirs and files are 777 but I need some specific files to be with other permissions.

Can I do this or there is any other option to do this?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to change the permissions for a specific folder and files in the PVC and the "chmod" command looks like running but doesn't do anything and the permissions are still set to 777 instead of my wanted permissions.

If you want to configure permissions in Kubernetes, you must use the [security context](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/):

> A security context defines privilege and access control settings for a Pod or Container. Security context settings include, but are not limited to:
>
> - Discretionary Access Control: Permission to access an object, like a file, is based on  [user ID (UID) and group ID (GID)](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/users_and_groups).
> - [Security Enhanced Linux (SELinux)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux): Objects are assigned security labels.
> - Running as privileged or unprivileged.
> - [Linux Capabilities](https://linux-audit.com/linux-capabilities-hardening-linux-binaries-by-removing-setuid/): Give a process some privileges, but not all the privileges of the root user.
> - [AppArmor](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/clusters/apparmor/): Use program profiles to restrict the capabilities of individual programs.
> - [Seccomp](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/clusters/seccomp/): Filter a process's system calls.
> - AllowPrivilegeEscalation: Controls whether a process can gain more privileges than its parent process. This bool directly controls whether the  [`no_new_privs`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/prctl/no_new_privs.txt)  flag gets set on the container process. AllowPrivilegeEscalation is true always when the container is: 1) run as Privileged OR 2) has  `CAP_SYS_ADMIN`.
> - readOnlyRootFilesystem: Mounts the container's root filesystem as read-only.
>
> The above bullets are not a complete set of security context settings -- please see  [SecurityContext](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.22/#securitycontext-v1-core)  for a comprehensive list.
>
> For more information about security mechanisms in Linux, see  [Overview of Linux Kernel Security Features](https://www.linux.com/learn/overview-linux-kernel-security-features)

In your case, if you want to grant permissions for a specific object (e.g. a file), you can use [Discretionary Access Control](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/07/18/11-ways-not-to-get-hacked/#8-run-containers-as-a-non-root-user):

> **Containers that run as root frequently have far more permissions than their workload requires which, in case of compromise, could help an attacker further their attack.**
>
> Containers still rely on the traditional Unix security model (called  [discretionary access control](https://www.linux.com/learn/overview-linux-kernel-security-features)  or DAC) - everything is a file, and permissions are granted to users and groups.

You can also [configure volume permission and ownership change policy for Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#configure-volume-permission-and-ownership-change-policy-for-pods).

See also:

- [Defining Privileges and Access Control Settings for Pods and Containers in Kubernetes](https://medium.com/kubernetes-tutorials/defining-privileges-and-access-control-settings-for-pods-and-containers-in-kubernetes-2cef08fc62b7)
- [11 Ways (Not) to Get Hacked](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/07/18/11-ways-not-to-get-hacked/#8-run-containers-as-a-non-root-user)

Comment: Hi @WytrzymałyWiktor,
This information was great but it doesn't solve my problem. I have succeeded to solve it by deploying another PVC from another STORAGE CLASS with different permissions.
Thank you anyway!